# SQL multiple values simple insert

Tags: sql, insert, mariadb

```
    INSERT INTO `forum01` (`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_4`) VALUES 
('1','2','3','4')
    ('','','','')
    ('','','','')
    ('','','','')
    ('','','','')
    ('','','','')
```

I get an error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; at line 2..
Isnt it a normal query? insert into the columns the following values..
Im trying it on localhost mariaDB.

Comment: Since this is mariaDB why tag it with sql server?

Comment: the question is about a sql command

Comment: And the syntax of sql statements vary based on the DBMS being used. The syntax you posted will work with MySql and MariaDB but will not work with sql server, oracle or a number of other DBMS. That is why you need to tag relevant DBMS to what you are working with.

Comment: ok thanks for editing..sql-server was in "advised tags" after i put sql tag

Comment: thanks for explaining everyone, got it to work like this: implode to put comas, then pick last value with end($array), preg_replace it with ("/,$/", ";"..), array_pop to dele the last array item and array_push the new line back to array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple values require a comma between them:

```
INSERT INTO `forum01` (`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_4`) 
    VALUES ('1','2','3','4'),
           ('','','',''),
           ('','','',''),
           ('','','',''),
           ('','','',''),
           ('','','','');
```

I should note that in many tables, one column or a group might be unique.  So, this might generate an error.  Also, don't use single quotes around a value if it should be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use comma after the (), as below

```
('1','2','3','4'),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','','')
--note the commas ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
create table forum01 (col_1 varchar(10),col_2 varchar(10),col_3 varchar(10),col_4 varchar(10) )
 INSERT INTO forum01 (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) VALUES 
('1','2','3','4'),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','','')
```